# Make a 'width: 100%' image placed below navigation become a background of navbar on mobiles

Tags: html, css

If you look at what happens here when you reduce the screen width is that the big photo becomes shorter and shorter, still filling in the full 100% of the width:

https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/

Now, I don't find that appealing and would like to make that photo disappear and become a background of the whole top (navbar) part once the navigation bar becomes the button. However, I would like only a certain part of the photo to show up, not the whole width.

Any hints on how to achieve that?

Update: the tricky part here is that each page has its own image. Since this is jekyll, in theory, I could add a css entry in the `<head>` of each generated page for setting the background image of the navbar, but I'm not sure whether there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: background-width and position?

Answer (score -1):

Put the picture as a background for your nav-bar and use the css background-position attributes.

Use viewport and let the image (the img-tag) disappear